# Double click in Excel overriding .Enabled status of checkbox form control?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet with a number of form controls (no ActiveX). There is a checkbox which must be ticked to unlock the adjacent cell, say "A2" and allow the user to select from a dropdown list within A2 using data validation. When the checkbox is unticked, cell A2 is locked.

In some circumstances I want to be able to disable the checkbox so that the user is unable to check it and therefore cannot change the value in A2.
In these circumstances I set the checkbox.enabled property to false. At first all appears to be fine. Clicking on the checkbox does not affect the locked status of cell A2. However, if I double click on the checkbox while it is disabled it seems to override the enabled=false status and enables it again?!

There are no on double click events or similar in my code so I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening? Strangely, I seem to be able to double click on it to override it when it is set to true, but once it is set to false after double clicking on it, it appears to be truly disabled and cannot be amended further with either a single or double click.

Edit - just to be clear, the checkbox still appears to  be disabled after double clicking it i.e. the value remains exactly as before. However, the onclick event has run as the adjacent cell is now unlocked whereas it was locked previously. So somehow a double click on the checkbox is calling an event even though it is disabled? I've tried to replicate this issue in a blank workbook but can't.

Comment: This will sound stupid, but... are you sure design mode is turned off?

Comment: Yep, not in design mode and the worksheet and workbook are both protected